# iterate over array and map result to an observable with rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I would like to build a tree object list which looks like this: `{name: string, fruits: Fruit[]}[]`
I get the tree from the backend with an empty fruit array and this can't be changed. Therefore I need to fetch the fruits separately. I would like to create a method which returns a complete tree object (filled fruit array) as an observable and takes a tree array as params. This is what I have tried:

```
getTreesWithFruits(trees: Tree[]): Observable<Tree[]> {
    trees.forEach(tree => {
        this.getFruits(tree).subscribe(fruits => {
            tree.fruits = fruits;
        });
    }),
}
```

obviously this doesn't work because I need to return the complete Tree[] as an observable. How can I solve this problem with RXJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from(trees).pipe(
  mergeMap(tree => 
    this.getFruits(tree).pipe(
      map(fruits => {
        tree.fruits = fruits;
        return tree;
      })
    )
  ),
  toArray()
)
```

If you don't want to call `this.getFruits` in parallel, then replace `mergeMap` with `concatMap`.